# Array of structures in table view

Tags: arrays, swift

There are a few questions about array of structures but I can't find any answer. Thanks in advance. 
I have the following array of structures:

```
var datosLibros = [BookData]()
```

The structure has the following data:

```
struct BookData {
var title: String
var author: String
var image: UIImage?
var isbn: String
```

}

The user make a search with an isbn and the book data is saved into this structure and appended into datosLibros.The search results are append to datosLibros by the following code:

```
 let libro = BookData(title: bookTitle!, author: bookAuthor!, image: bookCover, isbn: termino)
 datosLibros.append(libro)
```

I need to retrieve each title for a the cell text in a table view. I have tried this:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath)
    for  i in datosLibros  {
        cell.textLabel?.text = i.title
    }
    return cell
}
```

It seems to be working but only until another search is made. Then,  every cell title repeats itself with the last books title. 
Please tell me what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Do you append the search result to your datosLibros array?

Comment: Yes, I will show you how in the question after editing.

Comment: How are you populating datosLibros?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must retrieve the book from the array using `indexPath.row` as your array index. By using a for loop in the cellForItemAtIndexPath method, you're just setting the title of each cell to be the title of the last book in the array.

Try this:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let book = datosLibros[indexPath.row]
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath)

    cell.textLabel?.text = book.title

    return cell
}
```

After appending a book to `datasLibros`, you need to reload the table view using `tableView.reloadData()`.

Comment: worked like a charm!! Thanks!! Your explanation was very clear and now I understand why the title was repeating itself.